# Sci fi vintage movie about doppelgänger phenomena

Tags: story-identification

When I was a kid, I saw a movie on TV about a group of astronauts, and I remember there were three of them, but well I'm not really really sure. They landed on a planet similar to Earth, and they see themselves in a kind of field, meadow or garden.

I barely remember more, but something about these astronauts like seeing their own lives as memories or future in this planet. Don't know if one of them was seeing himself saying goodbye to his dying mother. Don't know much. I was like 6 years old. This was a color movie, probably of the 70s.

Comment: The excellent answers below likely have what you want: but conceivably, you could be just thinking of the well-known ending from *2001* - where Bowman sort of moves through time in a surreal way, while eating in a formal dining room (ultimately becoming - or something - a sort of huge floating baby-thing).  (No, really! :) )

Comment: @JoeBlow That reminds me, in the book that *Solaris* the movie is based on, there's also a huge baby! Although it's mentioned in the film (at least the 1972 version in my answer), it's sadly never seen – but it has been creepily featured in fan art: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rvsZG4V-Wus/UGEktQ0IXMI/AAAAAAAAANE/uyevuoayIL4/s1600/solaris_baby_color+copy.jpg and http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lZTLm4ZXsqI/UGF5HrE8qKI/AAAAAAAABaU/A-lY2zF7_EE/s1600/6RS.jpg

Comment: fascinating !!!  whoa seriously creepy! You know, Solaris ("the world's most boring film to sit through") has that amazing anecdote .. at one showing (festival or something), the *order of a few of the reels* got swapped around.  :) It is said that *even the Director did not actually notice*  :)

Answer (score 10):

### Could it be [*Solaris* from 1972](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069293/), by Andrei Tarkovsky?

> Sci fi vintage movie about doppelgänger phenomena

You don't actually mention the doppelgänger phenomena in your actual question, so I'm not sure what you remember about it, but in *Solaris* the eponymous sentient water planet can manifest physical simulacra based on the cosmonauts' memories. It creates a doppelgänger based on the main character's dead wife Hari, for example.

[image: Kelvin and Hari]

> a group of astronauts, and I remember there were three of them, but well I'm not really really sure.

The main character is Kris Kelvin, and he rendezvouses with his two colleagues Sartorius and Snaut on the Solaris space station.

[image: Kelvin and Sartorius]
[image: Snaut]

> They landed on a planet similar to Earth, and they see themselves in a kind of field, meadow or garden.

OK, Solaris is not really similar to Earth. It's completely covered by a sea, and can't normally be landed on, so the majority of the film takes place on a space station in orbit around the planet.

However, near the end of the film the sentient sea creates islands that can be landed on. There, it recreates the main character's memories from Earth, including a garden (and a memorable scene in a house which you might remember, inside which it eerily enough is raining) and a field/meadow.

[image: Field/meadow]

> I barely remember more, but something about these astronauts like seeing their own lives as memories or future in this planet. Don't know if one of them was seeing himself saying goodbye to his dying mother.

Kelvin, the main character, says goodbye to his father before leaving Earth, either because he is actually dying or because he's so old that he will be dead when Kelvin returns (it's not made clear which is the case); this is one of the memories he relives on Solaris.

[image: Kelvin and father]

> This was a color movie, probably of the 70s.

*Solaris* is from 1972. [Here's a trailer.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4vSPEDxGic)

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like an episode of "The Ray Bradbury Theater" called "Mars Is Heaven".
It starred Hal Linden as the leader of three astronauts who land on Mars and find an idyllic small American town populated by friends and relatives who are supposedly dead. Everything looks like it did on Earth, and there is a scene where the character played by Hal Linden encounters his mother. This episode aired in 1990, so it's off a bit from your description. You can watch the entire episode on Youtube, but here is the IMDb page:

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0683198/?ref_=rvi_tt

Here is the episode from Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like Mars is Heaven.........along with Ray Bradbury theater It was also a story in the NBC Martian Cronicles miniseries from the late 70s.

Comment: This is what the guest answered two days ago.